# Html rendering issue on Jquery datatable extra double quote

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

This is defined as one the field jquery datatable

```
var sedatatable = $('#customerTable').DataTable({
             "rowHeight": '5px',
            "searchHighlight": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "stateSave": true,
            "pageLength": 25,
            "ajax": {

                "url":"@Url.Action("GetList", "customers")",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json" ,
                //"cache": true
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "width": "50%" , className: "dt-body-center text-center"},
                {
                    "data": "name", "width": "55%", 
                    "render": function (data, type, full) {    

                        return '<a style="color:#337AB7"  onclick=EditSequencesName(' + data + ')>' + data + '</a>';


                    }
                }
            ],

      });
```

```html
var sedatatable, rowdata;
    sedatatable = $('#sequencesTable').DataTable({
                "rowHeight": '5px',
                "searchHighlight": true,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "stateSave": true,
                "pageLength": 25,
                "ajax": {

                    "url":"@Url.Action("GetList", "Customers")",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json" ,
                    //"cache": true
                },
                "columns": [

                    {
                        "data": "Active", "searchable": "false",
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            if (type === 'display') {

                                return '<input type="checkbox"   class="editor-active"/>';
                            }
                            return data;
                        },
                        "width":"5%",
                        className: "dt-body-center text-center"


                    },
                    {
                        "data": "ID", "width": "8%", className: "dt-body-center text-center"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Name", "width": "55%",
                        "render": function (data,type, row, full, meta) {

                            
                            return '<a style="color:#337AB7"  onclick="EditSequencesName(\'' + $.trim(data) + '\')">' + data + '</a>'; 
                             ; 


                        }
                    },
                     
                ],
                fixedColumns:   {
                    heightMatch: 'none'
                },
                rowCallback: function (row, data) {
                    // Set the checked state of the checkbox in the table
                    $('input.editor-active', row).prop('checked', data.Active == 1);

                }



            });
```

The developer tool shows  the second column render as

<a style="color:#337AB7" onclick="EditcustomerName(Test1" )>Test1</a

why there is an extra double quote after Test1 .

It shows the error as
(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Can you share more code about data?What is the value of data?

Comment: Test1  is the value of the data. Its coming from class  .Public class customer  { public string Name {get;set;}

Comment: Can you share where you return '<a style="color:#337AB7" onclick=EditcustomerName('+data+')>' + data +'';,and how convert it to html?

Comment: `onclick=EditcustomerName('+data+')` -> `onclick="EditcustomerName('+data+')"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 return '<a style="color:#337AB7"  onclick="EditSequencesName(\'' + $.trim(data) + '\')">' + data + '</a>'
```

The html render is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo:

Model:

```
public class CustomerTest {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

action:

```
public IActionResult GetList() {
            List<CustomerTest> l = new List<CustomerTest> { new CustomerTest { Id = 1, Name = "1" }, new CustomerTest { Id = 2, Name = "2" } };
            return new JsonResult(l);
        }
```

html:

```
<table id="customerTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
       
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       
</table>
```

js:

```
@section Scripts{
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var sedatatable = $('#customerTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url":"@Url.Action("GetList", "A")",
                type: 'GET',
                "dataSrc": "",
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "width": "50%" },
                {
                    "data": "name", "width": "55%",
                    "render": function (data, type, full) {


                        return '<a style="color:#337AB7"  onclick=EditSequencesName(' + data + ')>' + data + '</a>';


                    }
                }
            ],

      });
        })
    </script>

}
```

result:
[image]